# How does one enable or verify the REST interface of ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

I setup ActiveMQ 5.8.0 on a Windows 2003 virtual server for development purposes. I understand that there is suppose to be a REST interface for reading from and writing to queues and such. But, I can't seem to track down how to do it exactly. Port 8161 can be used to access the admin console, but every URL I try from Firefox Poster returns a 404. I tried URLs like these:

```
http://localhost:8161/queues <-- 404
http://localhost:61616/queues <-- some default message
http://localhost:61616/queue/inbox <-- same default message
http://localhost:8161/queue/inbox <-- 404
```

The documentation mentions mapping a URI to the servlet, but I'm not sure how or if I need to do this. The /demo feature is disabled by default, which is fine by me. How do I enable REST for my queues? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am also searching answer for the same question. Did you solve it????

Comment: I did not. The team I was working with switched from ActiveMQ to RabbitMQ, so I no longer need to know at this point. Sorry!

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but I found these pages: http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html & http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html

Answer (score 1):

As /demo is disabled, it been moved to /api
`http://localhost:8161/api/message/`

this is the path for all REST operations

Comment: Nothing shows up at that URL. Do you know how to enable the REST api functionality?